# Uploading a file sent via multipart form data in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, multipartform-data

I am building a site with a React frontend using the Wordpress API for the backend, and I am trying to handle a user-uploaded file sent via multipart form data.

After some Googling, I have been able to get the file metadata to appear in the "Media" section of the wp-admin dashboard, but the file is not being uploaded to the specified folder on the server.

I am brand new to WP and PHP, so I am pretty sure I am just making a simple mistake.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');

add_action('rest_api_init', 'submissionRoutes');

function submissionRoutes()
{
    register_rest_route('test/v1', 'manageSubmission', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'createSubmission',
    ));
}

function createSubmission($data)
{

    $file = $data->get_file_params()['file'];

    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $dir_name = 'forms/';

    $file_name = $dir_name . $file['name'];
    $file_type = wp_check_filetype(basename($file_name), null);

    $attachment = array(
        'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename($file_name),
        'post_mime_type' => $file_type['type'],
        'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($file_name)),
    );

    $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file);

    return $data->get_file_params();
}
```

Eventually, I would like to upload the submitted file along with other text-based form data (the user's name, etc.) into a single post. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The function `wp_insert_attachment` only inserts/updates the database, it doesn’t do anything to the file system. Check out [`media_handle_upload`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_upload/) which might work, but if not, the source of that function should.

Answer (score 0):

After some more Googling and with the help of the comments above, I ended up finding a solution that worked. Here is what I ended up with (including the code to attach the uploaded file to a post).

Note: I am using the ACF plugin for custom fields.

```
function createSubmission($data){
    $name = sanitize_text_field($data['name']);
    $tel = sanitize_text_field($data['tel']);
    if (!$name || !$tel) {
        return 'ERROR NO NAME OR TEL';
    }
    $date = date("_Y-M-d-Gi");
    $post_id = wp_insert_post(array(
        'post_type' => 'submission',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $name) . '_' . $date,
        'meta_input' => array(
            'name' => $name,
            'tel' => $tel,
        )
    ));

    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    $file = $data->get_file_params()['file'];
    $filename = $name . $date . '.pdf';
    $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
    $supported_types = array('application/pdf');
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($file['name'], null);

    if (!in_array($wp_filetype['type'], $supported_types)) {
        return 'ERROR - wrong type!';
    }

    $upload_file = wp_upload_bits($filename, null, file_get_contents($file_tmp));

    if (!$upload_file['error']) {

        $attachment = array(
            'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
            'post_parent' => $post_id,
            'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename),
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'inherit'
        );

        $attachment_id =  wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $upload_file['file'], $post_id);
        update_field('application', $attachment_id, $post_id);

        return $post_id;
    }
}
```